# Maximizing the number of concurrent tests in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Due to hitting a memory bottleneck when running multiple concurrent tests in separate browser instances, I was wondering if reusing same browser instance might help to mitigate this?

I have considered using different tabs on the same browser instance, but since I have no control of the tests that will be executed (that is I can't modify them) I am not entirely sure it even possible to do in a reliable way. Are there any security or reliability implications versus separate browser instances ?

Are there any other optimizations that can be done to increase the number of concurrent tests running on the same machine?

P.S. We are using mostly Firefox, Chrome, and IE drivers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to open multiple tabs.  You can run multiple browsers at the same time though, on the same machine.   I have ran multiple Firefox, multiple IE, and multiple Chrome, up to 5 instances.   It is made easier when using Grid.  For example: you can have one Grid node on a remote machine and run 3 IE, 3 Chrome, and 3 Firefox through that one node simultaneously.    I get around all of this by just using SauceLabs, but if you made your own Grid server and had multiple Node servers, then you could do similar.

Also, when using TestNG, you can re-use those instances (mentioned above) as long as your webdriver instance has a scope throughout the class.  In that case, all class Test methods could re-share the same instance that was started.  I have done that before also but with multi-threaded Grid browsers running you just need to be careful with being accurate with your Java coding practices to avoid any problems.

In this case I would create a TestBase class that contains the WebDriver instance and then the Test class that extends it will be able to allow all methods in that test class instance to share that browser instance.   Then, you can finally quit the browser in the @AfterTest configuration annotation.   [Here is an example](https://github.com/djangofan/simple-selenium-builder-framework) I wrote recently.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to split your tests into multiple test suites and run them on different servers for even more parallel execution.